# How to stack divs by click on image

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to make a div appear stacked on top of another one, by clicking on a button/image?

The problem I have: 
I want a poster to appear if I click on it in the selector. 
 I want it to stay, once I click on another poster, which then will stack on top of the previous one. 
 Is it possible to make this a loop, so no matter how often I click different objects the old divs will always stay below the newest one?

(See pictures attached)

first click:
[image]

second click:
[image]

and so on...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes it is possible. What have you tried so far, where are you stuck? PS: this will require scripting in any case (loop => keeping an accurate counter). The rest is just a question of z-index.

Comment: I tried it with z-index, but I think I failed it...

<div class="poster-main">
    <img src="assets/img/Poster/Sichtbarkeit_2_2.png" alt="..." class="img-poster2">
    <img src="assets/img/Poster/Marathon2.png" alt="..." class="img-poster">

   </div>

.img-poster {
 z-index: 9999;
  max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.img-poster2 {
 z-index: 9998;
 position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.poster-main {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

Comment: The solution to your problem is really simple: make the image a child of preview div that is relatively positioned, make these child images, absolutely positioned, then give every new child image a higher z-index than the previous ones.

Comment: You need to **post** your **code** here (preferably in a snippet) so we can test it, and modify to give you a solution.

Comment: sorry, just joined here. Thanks for the advise, will fix my question! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will cut down the explaination to some documentations such as [how to create an element through JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement). Teachign every single step would blow the scope of Stackoverflow.

If you know how to create an element through JS you need a variable such as `counter` in my code that is raised by every single time you run the script with: `counter = counter + 1`

You set a z-index through JS with `element.style.zIndex = variable`and thanks to the rising counter it will set the new element over the other element (z-axis-wise).

To rotate the element you can use `transform: rotate()` which I randomized by calling a variable: `rotation = Math.round(Math.random() * 40 - 20);` which will randomize a number between `-20` and `20`.

```js
var preview = document.querySelector('.preview'),
    counter = '1';
    picture = ''
    
function addRed() {
  picture = 'red';
  addPicture();
}

function addGreen() {
  picture = 'green';
  addPicture();
}

function addBlue() {
  picture = 'blue';
  addPicture();
}

function addYellow() {
  picture = 'yellow';
  addPicture();
}

function addPicture() {
  var img = document.createElement('img'),
      rotation = Math.round(Math.random() * 40 - 20);
  switch (picture) {
    case 'red':
      img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/350.jpg/FF0000';
      break;
    case 'green':
      img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/350.jpg/00FF00';
      break;
    case 'blue':
      img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/350.jpg/0000FF';
      break;
    case 'yellow':
      img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/350.jpg/FFFF00';
      break;
  }
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  img.style.top = '50%';
  img.style.left = '50%';
  img.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)';
  img.style.zIndex = counter;  
  preview.appendChild(img);
  
  var counter = counter + 1;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.preview {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  position: relative;
}

.selector {
  padding: 10px;
}

.selector > img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="selector"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg/FF0000" onclick="addRed()"></div>
  <div class="selector"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg/00FF00" onclick="addGreen()"></div>
  <div class="selector"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg/0000FF" onclick="addBlue()"></div>
  <div class="selector"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg/FFFF00" onclick="addYellow()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: tacoshy, your solution worked very good! Just one last question, ist there a way, to add one image, that is already displayed on page load, but not in the selector list? So you would only see it, once refreshed the page, and it will disappear beneath the other images once they were selected in the selector? I tried by adding a simple <img> between preview and selector, but when resizing it wouldn't adapt to the properties of the big displayed image. your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `div` called `preview`, and makes its `position` `relative`. This is necessary because this creates a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).
2. Create another container that will hold the list of images to choose from. *I choose a `section` with an unordered list which will contain these images as list elements.*
3. Set `overflow-x` `auto`, so a scrollbar appears once the amount of images exceed the container width.
4. In your stylesheet, select the images which are child of our `preview` div, and make their `position` `absolute`, with a `top` margin of `0`. This makes sure that all images are stacked in the same x-y direction. This works because the `preview` div also has `display: flex`, with `align-items: center` as well as `justify-content: center`.
5. In your script file, select these list images - *I called them `posters`.*

```
const posters = document.querySelectorAll(".poster");
```

6. Create two variables called `zIndex` ( = 1) and `rotated` ( = true).
7. Attach an event listener to each of the poster image inside this list of images, using a `for...of` loop.

```
for (const poster of posters) {
  poster.addEventListener("click", () => onPosterClicked(poster));
}
```

8. In this event handler, we select the `preview` div, and clone the clicked image using `cloneNode()` method. We also give it `class` of `shown` so, our styling for images inside `preview` work.
9. We then increment the z-index, and assign this incremented z-index to this cloned image's style.

```
cloned.style.zIndex = ++zIndex;
```

10. For decorational purposes, we switch between rotated and non-rotated transforms, so each image new image added is rotated differently to our previous image.

```
if (rotated) {
    cloned.style.transform = "rotate(-5deg)";
}
rotated = !rotated;
```

*Note: We can achieve this rotation directly through CSS, by using `nth-child` selectors.*

11. Finally, we append this cloned image to our `preview` div.

```
preview.appendChild(cloned);
```

The complete code looks like this:

```js
function onPosterClicked(poster) {
  const preview = document.querySelector(".preview");
  const cloned = poster.cloneNode();
  cloned.classList = "shown";
  cloned.style.zIndex = ++zIndex;

  if (rotated) {
    cloned.style.transform = "rotate(-5deg)";
  }
  rotated = !rotated;
  preview.appendChild(cloned);
}

const posters = document.querySelectorAll(".poster");
let zIndex = 1;
let rotated = true;

for (const poster of posters) {
  poster.addEventListener("click", () => onPosterClicked(poster));
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.preview {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.shown {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.list {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4rem 2rem;
}

.list ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  gap: 5px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  list-style: none;
}

.poster {
  max-height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="preview">
    <img class="shown" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="test image" />
  </div>
  <section class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img class="poster" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="sample poster image" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class="poster" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="sample poster image" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class="poster" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="sample poster image" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class="poster" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="sample poster image" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class="poster" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="sample poster image" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class="poster" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="sample poster image" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class="poster" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="sample poster image" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img class="poster" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="sample poster image" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <script async defer src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```